# How to decrease query time from 50,000,000

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a mysql query optimization for simple query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM consumer WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'JAMES' and LASTNAME='ADAMS' and City = '*' and State = '*';
```

The table have 50,000,000 records. 
Executing time is 8mins. 
Could you help me how to decrease the time?

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM consumer
WHERE FIRSTNAME = 'JAMES' and LASTNAME = 'ADAMS' and City = '*' and State = '*';
```

You want an index.  I would recommend `consumer(LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, City, State)`.

That said, your query should not be taking 8 minutes on 50,000 rows.  I can only think of two reasonable explanations:

- Something is locking the table.
- Your rows are really, really wide, so lots of data is being returned.

It is also possible that other processes on your database server are using lots of resources.  Or that you have ancient, pathetically slow tertiary storage, or something like that.

Comment: Possible to include the `City` and `State` fields in the index as well.  The example given is looking for a literal '*' not a wildcard (not a `like` clause)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer . . . The OP changed the question after I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1) add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE consumer ADD INDEX (LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME);
```

2) what value does specify city & state = '*' add to the query? Is that some special value in your database or are you looking for any city/state? If the former, then add those fields to the index. If the latter, then drop that from the where clause.